# updating default dictionary with new key and value

Tags: python, dictionary, object, data-structures

I need to add to a default dictionary some keys and values before using it in a different script to display it in a GUI.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_dict = { 
               'dict1' : {
                   'col1' : value1,
                   'col2' : value2,
                   ...
               },
               'dict2' : {
                   'col1' : value1,
                   'col2' : value2,
               }
               ...

    def set_attribute(self, dict, col, val)
        self.my_dict[dict][col] = val

    def set_attributes(self, dict, **kwargs):
        for col, val in kwargs.items():
            self.set_attribute(dict, col, val)

    def get_attribute(self, dict, col):
        if dict in self.my_dict:
            return self.my_dict[dict].get(col)
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_obj = MyClass()
    value = my_obj.my_dict.get_attribute('dict', 'col1') * .011
    my_obj.my_dict.set_attribute('dict1', 'col3', value)
```

This works for updating the dictionary to contain the new col name and value but when I run it from my other script I only get the default dictionary and not the updated one.

main.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from dictclass import MyClass

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    print(myclass_obj.my_dict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    myclass_obj = MyClass()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If you want the `MyClass` object to change its behavior, then you need to do that in the class code.  Even if you get rid of the `if`,the `MyClass` object you create in the first file is completely unrelated to the `MyClass` object you create in the second file.

Comment: as in create another method to add the values?

Comment: @Willy Add a function to the other script which creates an updated instance of `MyClass` and returns it. This function can then be used by both scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this based on [Tim Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883316/tim-roberts) comment

I added to myclass.py this method

```
def update_dictionary(self):
    value = self.get_attribute('dict', 'col1') * .011
    self.set_attribute('dict1', 'col3', value)
```

within main.py I called it.

```
class MainWindow():
    ...
        self.myclass_obj = myclass_obj
        self.myclass_obj.update_dictionary()
        self.myclass_obj.my_dict
```

Comment: You don't need `get`/`set` here.  Just `self.my_dict['dict1']['col1'] *= 0.011` will do it.